# What does "upgrade volume detected" mean when creating a bootable usb stick?

Tags: installation, boot, usb

When creating a bootable usb stick for Ubuntu 12.04 server edition, the startup disk creator pops up the "installation complete" window *and* another window titled "Upgrade volume detected" which says the following:

> **A distribution volume with software packages has been detected.**
>
> Would you like to try to upgrade from it automatically?

With options to `cancel` or `Run upgrade`. What distribution volume is  it talking about and where did it detect it? What does "upgrade from it automatically mean"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you mount a CD or USB device that has an Ubuntu OS on it (either the same version or a newer, I think), Ubuntu will detect it and offer to upgrade. So, my guess is that after you create the bootable USB or CD, it gets automatically mounted, and Ubuntu goes through the normal detection routine.

You can confirm this by unmounting, then reinserting the device to see if you get the same message.